# Unable to read datetime data with STR_TO_DATE() in MySQL LOAD operation

Tags: mysql, load, str-to-date

My Table looks like this

```
!mysql praxisDB -e 'desc eCommerce'
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| InvoiceNo   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| StockCode   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Description | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Quantity    | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| InvoiceDate | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| UnitPrice   | float(6,2)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| customerID  | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country     | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The input data in a CSV file looks like this

```
!head eCommerce_02PC_2021.csv
InvoiceNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,InvoiceDate,UnitPrice,CustomerID,Country
C544414,22960,JAM MAKING SET WITH JARS,-2,2/18/2011 14:54,3.75,13408.0,United Kingdom
555276,48111,DOORMAT 3 SMILEY CATS,1,6/1/2011 17:28,15.79,,United Kingdom
575656,22952,60 CAKE CASES VINTAGE CHRISTMAS,48,11/10/2011 14:29,0.55,13319.0,United Kingdom
571636,20674,GREEN POLKADOT BOWL,16,10/18/2011 11:41,1.25,13509.0,United Kingdom
576657,22556,PLASTERS IN TIN CIRCUS PARADE ,12,11/16/2011 11:03,1.65,12720.0,Germany
569823,23298,SPOTTY BUNTING,1,10/6/2011 12:15,4.95,16895.0,United Kingdom
570185,21090,WET/MOULDY,-192,10/7/2011 14:56,0.0,,United Kingdom
574943,17091J,VANILLA INCENSE IN TIN,36,11/8/2011 7:52,0.38,13026.0,United Kingdom
561902,22909,SET OF 20 VINTAGE CHRISTMAS NAPKINS,96,7/31/2011 15:50,0.85,17404.0,Sweden
```

My LOAD command looks like this

```
!mysql praxisDB -e "   \
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/content/eCommerce_02PC_2021.csv' INTO TABLE eCommerce \
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES  \
(  InvoiceNo,  StockCode,  Description,  Quantity,@InvoiceDate, UnitPrice, customerID,country) \
set InvoiceDate = STR_TO_DATE(@InvoiceDate, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i') \
"
```

All the rows are getting loaded but the output looks like this

```
!mysql praxisDB -e 'select * from eCommerce limit 9'
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| InvoiceNo | StockCode | Description                         | Quantity | InvoiceDate         | UnitPrice | customerID | country        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| C544414   | 22960     | JAM MAKING SET WITH JARS            |       -2 | NULL                |      3.75 | 13408.0    | United Kingdom |
| 555276    | 48111     | DOORMAT 3 SMILEY CATS               |        1 | NULL                |     15.79 |            | United Kingdom |
| 575656    | 22952     | 60 CAKE CASES VINTAGE CHRISTMAS     |       48 | NULL                |      0.55 | 13319.0    | United Kingdom |
| 571636    | 20674     | GREEN POLKADOT BOWL                 |       16 | 2011-10-18 11:41:00 |      1.25 | 13509.0    | United Kingdom |
| 576657    | 22556     | PLASTERS IN TIN CIRCUS PARADE       |       12 | 2011-11-16 11:03:00 |      1.65 | 12720.0    | Germany        |
| 569823    | 23298     | SPOTTY BUNTING                      |        1 | 2011-10-06 00:15:00 |      4.95 | 16895.0    | United Kingdom |
| 570185    | 21090     | WET/MOULDY                          |     -192 | NULL                |      0.00 |            | United Kingdom |
| 574943    | 17091J    | VANILLA INCENSE IN TIN              |       36 | 2011-11-08 07:52:00 |      0.38 | 13026.0    | United Kingdom |
| 561902    | 22909     | SET OF 20 VINTAGE CHRISTMAS NAPKINS |       96 | NULL                |      0.85 | 17404.0    | Sweden         |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
```

The input date data looks identically formatted in all the rows but some of them are getting captured and converted correctly but in others ( in fact in a majority) they are being set to NULL. Would be grateful if someone could help me identify where I am making a mistake.

Could the presence of two commas on the second and seventh row of data have a material impact?

I am running this inside Google Colab, hence all sql commands are prefixed by !

Comment: Your pattern is incorrect, you use date pattern with leading zeros whereas the data does not contain them. I.e., for example, `%m` for month is not correct, use `%c`. Also `%h` -> `%H`, not 12h am/pm but 24h. Study format specifiers, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Thanks. %H brings down the number of errors significantly. To the point that the data can be used for further analysis